# Updating UI when it's onPause or in background

Tags: android, user-interface

I have two activities, A and B. If A is started and then B is started, the A goes to onPause.

In this situation, if I want to update UI of Activity A, what should I do?

I don't have any problem with it on emulator. I mean in this situation I can update UI of Activity A without any problem, but it doesn't work on a real device(cell phone) and noting changed.

What is the solution/solutions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because A is paused, there is no need to update the UI (textviews, listviews, spinners, whatever). You may be talking about update some info inside A from B. If you want to pass some new information from B to A, you should the `startActivityForResult()` method or similar to let A wait for some results, and pass some extras from B to A. Then, you can truly update A's UI from `onResume()` method (you need to override it)

Get an example [here](http://android.rahulblogs.com/android-startactivityforresult-example/)

Comment: I have a class that includes all my const, views and handles my messages and other activities are extended from this class. The activity A is updated by information which comes from another device via Bluetooth. So I get information then update views in that class. So I don't need to pass information from activities because I have a reference class.

Comment: In that case, the moment you should update information when coming from activity B is inside the `onResume()` method or after receiving information from the other devices.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it. I'm exhausted, I don't know why is too difference  between an emulator and a real device :(

Comment: It shouldn't. It's just that not every device is equal to another, and maybe doing some changes to from one or another place is not as you should do on the first place

Answer (score 0):

You could update the UI in the `onResume()` of Activity A. You can put the updated info into an `Intent` and use that to start `Activity` A. In the `onResume()` of `Activity` A you take the info from the `Intent` using the `getIntent()` method then update the UI as needed.